# how to send data from mobile to mobile except SMS

Tags: android

I'm using C2DM in my Application to send data from mobile to mobile
But C2DM uses Google server(lacks data confidentiality) to redirect messages to device.
Is there any other way for sending data from mobile to mobile directly without any third party server? 
I dont want to use SMS in my App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on requirement (1) Without third party server (2) Between 2 mobiles.

Your options are limited to these:

1. WiFi Direct (Ad Hoc Network)
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html
2. Bluetooth
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html
3. NFC
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html

Comment: Thanks,But WiFI, Bluethooth, NFC works within a range. I want to send data globally across any mobile. currently i'm using C2DM. But for data security i dont want to use c2dm. Is there any other way to send data. how to create chat App between 2 mobiles. both mobiles are not within a range. How to do it?

Comment: (1) Create a chat web server and both phones login using browser OR (2) Develop an app (most likely an android service) to accept push message from your server and notify your user.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly said "no third party server". But may I suggest xmpp. I've had good luck with smack derived jars and OpenFire. You get a lot of flexible and easy to use functionality out of the box. It may be your best bet for chat type applications.

We host our own instance of OpenFire and authenticate against Active Directory. The XMPP protocol provides the user/device addressing, routing, and, optionally, store and forward capabilities.

It also makes it easy to exchange device data with applications written for other operating systems and in other languages. XMPP IQ packets can be used for lookup type transactions without the overhead of a Chat type connection (no presence information, back end XEP-114 plug ins to connect with server side resources).

Answer (score 0):

Not really: your device has to know which device to connect to. You *could* theoretically do that if you know the IP of the device, but with mobile phones this changes frequently and I'm not even sure if mobile providers will let you connect directly to devices on their network. So, you're at least going to need a 'step' in between the two phones that you can trust to be stable.

What you could do is set up your own server, and let a user (user1) upload messages to your server addressed to a specific sender (user2). When the message is received, you can use C2DM to send a signal to user2's phone, and attach the message's unique identifier to this. When user2's app receives this message, you can proceed to download the message content from your webserver.

If you don't want to use any webserver at all, you're limited to the options mentioned by Calvin: WiFi, bluetooth or NFC.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately having a direct socket connection between mobiles phones is almost impossible as they invariably are behind firewall. BTW also look at https://www.alljoyn.org/ Its an interesting technology as well.